# Where is the coolant fan relay on a 2001 Monte Carlo SS

Tags: electrical, chevrolet

My check engine light is on. Shop failed the car for NY state inspection. Says I have a bad coolant fan relay. Where would this relay be located?

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I bought and changed (1) of the three relays. is there something I need to do to clear the check engine light? it's still on.

Comment: You can unplug the battery for about a half hour or take it to Autozone or the like. They can clear the codes for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your Monte Carlo has two separate fuse blocks. One inside the cabin of the car and one under the hood. If you pop your hood, you should see something which looks like this:

[image]

In the picture, the relays are going to be under the left side panel. They are the three which are lined up on the right side of that block (this is relative to the picture ... orient the picture to your fuse block in car). One of those relays is going to be bad. It should be a square block which is either grey or black. When you pull it out, it should have four tangs on the underside which plugs into the block.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I bought and changed (1) of the three relays. is there something I need to do to clear the check engine light? it's still on.

Comment: @william ... Are you positive you changed out the right relay? If so, you can clear the codes with an OBD-II reader.